# MySQL GROUP By count

Tags: mysql

```
ID| FROM |  TO   |     Type    |
--|------|-------|-------------|
1 | Brij |Nilesh |   Call_In   |
--|------|-------|-------------|
2 |Jaydip| Vipul |   Call_In   |
--|------|-------|-------------|  
3 |Rajesh|Nilesh |   Call_In   |
--|------|-------|-------------|
4 |Jaydip| vipul |   Call_Out  |
--|------|-------|-------------|
5 |Jaydip| vipul |   Call_In   |
--|------|-------|-------------|
6 | Brij | Nilesh|   Call_Out  |
--|------|-------|-------------|
7 |vipul | Brij  |   Call_In   |
```

So i used to get most frequent pair from data using this query

```
Select FROM,TO, COUNT('FROM' & 'TO') AS howmany
from table
GROUP BY FROM,TO
```

Which gives me result like this

```
  FROM  |   TO   |howmany|
--------|--------|-------|
  Brij  | Nilesh |   2   |
--------|--------|-------|
 Jaydip | Vipul  |   3   |
--------|--------|-------|
 Rajesh | Nilesh |   1   |
--------|--------|-------|
 vipul  | Brij   |   1   |
```

But i also want the sum of type of calls In these group like

```
Brij  | Nilesh |howmany| Call_In | Call_Out |
------|--------|-------|---------|----------|
Jaydip| vipul  |   3   |    2    |    1     |
------|--------|-------|---------|----------|
Brij  | Nilesh |   2   |    1    |    1     |
------|--------|-------|---------|----------|
Rajesh| Nilesh |   1   |    1    |    0     |
------|--------|-------|---------|----------|
vipul | Brij   |   1   |    1    |    0     |
```

So please suggest me query for that

Comment: The query in your question doesn't look too good...

Comment: reserverd-word column names of FROM, TO, Type are a) a bad idea and b) should be escaped `\`FROM\``, `\`TO\``, etc.

Comment: Don't forget `table` :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT FROM, TO, COUNT(*) AS howmany,
       SUM(Type = 'Call_In') AS Call_In, SUM(Type = 'Call_Out') AS Call_Out
FROM table
GROUP BY FROM, TO
```

Comment: You forgot to add table ?? Where to add table name ??

Comment: Fixed. It gets added in the normal place.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Select 
  `FROM`, `TO`, 
  COUNT(*) AS howmany,
  SUM(CASE Type WHEN 'Call_In' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Call_In,
  SUM(CASE Type WHEN 'Call_Out' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Call_Out
from table GROUP BY `FROM`, `TO`
```

Comment: there problem in query keywords may be i'm using Reserved keywords but even after enclosing all header fields in [] problem could not be solved . . . .

Comment: Fields named after reserved keywords in MySQL should be enclosed in _backticks_ (``).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your comments i got it i just added count of types of calls so i can add it to futher use

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
Select FROM, TO, COUNT(*) AS howmany,
  sum(case when type = 'Call_In' then 1 else 0 end) as Call_In,
  sum(case when type = 'Call_Out' then 1 else 0 end) as Call_Out
from table 
GROUP BY FROM,TO
```

Comment: Actually i'm using this query in VB.net and i got this error ! " IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005) "