# Select count if column name contain and value equal to something MYSQL

Tags: mysql, select, count, multiple-columns

Here is my table call TrainingPresence

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Name  | FootNov12 | HandNov15 | FootNov22 |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Clem  | x         | Abs       | Abs       |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Kevin | x         | x         | x         |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I want to select the name and the number of time when player came to the Foot training.

```
FootNov12 = Football Novembrre 12th
FootNov22 = Football November 22th
HandNov15 = Handball November 15th
```

The select query should give me :

```
Name | Count
Clem |  1
Kevin|  2
```

But I don't know how to do it
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Need to add more information to your questions so that others can understand your question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please put some efforts in framing a question with **relevant and minimal sample data** showcasing your requirements, and **corresponding expected output**. Please read this link: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: I edited my post to add more information, sorry about it. Is this better?.

Comment: You need to [unpivot](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+unpivot) in a [subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/derived-tables.html) before you can [GROUP BY and COUNT()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19279509/mysql-group-by-count) .. So basically this question is a duplicate here..

Comment: Seriously consider revising your schema. A database table is NOT a spreadsheet!!

Comment: Seriously I'm learning, I'm not a champion! remember when you started using a database ! ;)

Answer (score 1):

A normalised Schema might look like this

```
users
user_id name
1       Clem
2       Kevin

training
user_id date       sport 
      1 2018-11-15 Handball
      1 2018-11-11 Football
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So I need 2 tables right?

Comment: The force is strong in this one

Comment: @clementpignet Actually you'd probably have a table of users, a schedule table, and a table of attendance. You might also have a table of sports.